# Structuring Javascript Array Data

Tags: javascript, arrays

hope I can get some help here.

I have a javascript array that looks like so:

```
var stages = ['Stage 1', 'Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 3', 'Stage 1'];
var stageValues = [10, 20, 10, 30, 50];
```

What I would like to achieve is to take the above data and have it transformed into something like this:

```
Stage 1: 10, 20, 50
Stage 2: 10
Stage 3: 30
```

Kind of a bit stumped on how to do this...  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over two arrays and group it.
But much more easier will be the functional approach with some library like underscore or lodash

```
var stages = ['Stage 1', 'Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 3', 'Stage 1'];
var stageValues = [10, 20, 10, 30, 50];

var grouped = _.groupBy(stageValues, function (elem, index) {
    return stages[index];
});
```

Comment: Wow this is actually an awesome library.. Seems to have taken a bit of the hard work away and easily grouped them.. So many thanks for pointing me to this..

Many thanks for all the other answers as well.  But is there a way I can convert the resulting json object into html readable format so it can be displayed on a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. The function returns an object key/value where each key is an element of the first array and the value is an array made of corresponding elements of the second array.

```
function joint_arrays(arr1,arr2) {  
  toR = {};
  if (arr1.length===arr2.length){    
    for (var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
      if (arr1[i] in toR) {
        toR[arr1[i]].push(arr2[i]);
      }
      else {
        toR[arr1[i]] = [arr2[i]];
      }
    }
  }
  return toR;  
}
```

For example:

```
var res= joint_arrays(stages,stageValues);
console.log(res);
```

returns

```
[object Object] {
  Stage 1: [10, 20, 50],
  Stage 2: [10],
  Stage 3: [30]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var stages = ['Stage 1', 'Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 3', 'Stage 1'],
    stageValues = [10, 20, 10, 30, 50],
    obj = stages.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        r[a] = r[a] || [];
        i in stageValues && r[a].push(stageValues[i]);
        return r;
    }, {});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```